# cmp in if statement (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

```
if [ cmp -s "$expectedOut" "$actualOut" ]; then
```

The following line of code keeps giving me errors saying that there are too many arguments. however I know this is the proper typical use of cmp so I think it may have to do with the brackets. Anyone know whats really going on here?

Comment: `[` is not part of `if` syntax -- it's a separate command with its own syntax. If you want to run `cmp`, run `cmp`, not `[`.

Answer (score 5):

Lose the `[` `]`.

```
if cmp -s "$expectedOut" "$actualOut" ; then
```

The syntax of `if` is

```
if Command; then
```

`[` is just one possible command (on that happens to expect `]` as its last argument to make things look pretty).

Comment: this only allows for 1 comparison, what if i need to do 2 `cmp`?